# empty log after commit

Tags: svn

After creating a new svn-depot and committing a file I get an empty log. I did the following:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ svnadmin create depot
$ # copy empty depot to the work repo
$ svn co file:///home/antoras/dev/java/tmp/depot/ work
$ cd work
$ touch test
$ svn add test
$ svn commit -m "fist commit"
$ svn log
```

After this the only output I get is a single line with `-`-signs. But I wanna have the commit message. What did I wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `svn log -r HEAD:1` or `svn up && svn log` instead. Without revision arguments, `svn log` shows the log up to the revision of the working directory (or the specified paths). After `svn commit`, the local revision of the committed files is updated - but the working directory has still the previous revision. You can check this behavior with `svn info`. Try the following command after the commit operation:

```
svn info . test
```